# Dealing with piecewise equations returned by sympy integrate

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

In sympy I have an integral which returns a Piecewise object, e.g.

```
In [2]: from sympy.abc import x,y,z

In [3]: test = exp(-x**2/z**2)

In [4]: itest = integrate(test,(x,0,oo))

In [5]: itest
Out[5]: 
⎧   ___                                                   
⎪ ╲╱ π ⋅z       │                 ⎛      1          ⎞│   π
⎪ ───────   for │periodic_argument⎜──────────────, ∞⎟│ ≤ ─
⎪    2          │                 ⎜          2      ⎟│   2
⎪               │                 ⎝polar_lift (z)   ⎠│    
⎪                                                         
⎪∞                                                        
⎪⌠                                                        
⎨⎮    2                                                   
⎪⎮  -x                                                    
⎪⎮  ───                                                   
⎪⎮    2                                                   
⎪⎮   z                                                    
⎪⎮ ℯ    dx                    otherwise                   
⎪⌡                                                        
⎪0                                                        
⎩
```

I would like to extract just the first branch of this piecewise equation, in other words, I would like to be able to do something like `itest.parts(0)`to extract simply `sqrt(pi)*z/2`. I can't seem to find any way to do this, but perhaps I am using the wrong search terms in the documentation. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Poking around a bit, I've managed to find that if I do `itest.args[0][0]` I can extract this expression. This seems like a bit of a hack, however. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, using `.args` is the correct way to access parts of an expression.

In this case, though, there is an option to `integrate` that will let you ignore convergence conditions

```
In [39]: integrate(test, (x, 0, oo), conds='none')
Out[39]:
  ___
╲╱ π ⋅z
───────
   2
```

Also, if you explicitly set the assumptions that you know on your variables, often the convergence conditions resolve themselves (it doesn't seem to happen in this case for any simple assumptions on `z`, though).  For example, if you knew that `z` was real, use `z = Symbol('z', real=True)`. Usually assuming that things are real, or even better positive, when you know it will help a lot in ensuring convergence.